# will ~ operator change the data type?

Tags: c

When I read someone's code I find that he bothered to write an explicite type cast.

```
 #define ULONG_MAX ((unsigned long int) ~(unsigned long int) 0)
```

When I write code

```
  1 #include<stdio.h>
  2 int main(void)
  3 {
  4         unsigned long int max;
  5         max = ~(unsigned long int)0;
  6         printf("%lx",max);
  7         return 0;
  8 }
```

it works as well. Is it just a meaningless coding style?

Comment: no `~` not change the data until you use `=`  eg. `i = ~i` i will be change but simply `~i` doesn't chage `i`, also `~` gives 1's complement

Comment: Whoever wrote that probably didn't know that they could have written it as `max = ~0UL;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you read is very bad, for several reasons.

- First of all user code should never define `ULONG_MAX`. This is a reserved identifier and *must* be provided by the compiler implementation.
- That definition is not suitable for use in a preprocessor `#if`. The `_MAX` macros for the basic integer types *must* be usable there.
- `(unsigned long)0` is just crap. Everybody should just use `0UL`, unless you *know* that you have a compiler that is not compliant with all the recent C standards with that respect. (I don't know of any.)
- Even `~0UL` should not be used for that value, since `unsigned long` may (theoretically) have padding bits. `-1UL` is more appropriate, because it doesn't deal with the bit pattern of the value. It uses the guaranteed arithmetic properties of unsigned integer types. `-1` will always be the  maximum value of an unsigned type. So `~` may only be used in a context where you are absolutely certain that `unsigned long` has no padding bits. But as such using it makes no sense. `-1` serves better.
- "recasting" an expression that is known to be `unsigned long` is just superfluous, as you observed. I can't imagine any compiler that bugs on that.

Recasting of expression *may* make sense when they are used in the preprocessor, but only under very restricted circumstances, and they are interpreted differently, there.

```
#if ((uintmax_t)-1UL) == SOMETHING
..
#endif
```

Here the value on the left evalues to `UINTMAX_MAX` in the preprocessor *and* in later compiler phases. So

```
#define UINTMAX_MAX ((uintmax_t)-1UL)
```

would be an appropriate definition for a compiler implementation.

To see the value for the preprocessor, observe that there `(uintmax_t)` is not a cast but an unknown identifier token inside `()` and that it evaluates to `0`. The minus sign is then interpreted as binary minus and so we have `0-1UL` which is unsigned and thus the max value of the type. But that trick only works if the cast contains a single identifier token, not if it has three as in your example, and if the integer constant has a `-` or `+` sign.

Comment: OP said below that the code is part of `glibc` (`stdlib/strtol_l.c`). I'm not saying you're wrong, but in the case of a standard library implementation there *may* be some non-obvious issues...

Comment: The preprocessor does not understand casts. Your example will attempt to subtract 1 from an identifier named `uintmax_t` and compare the result with `SOMETHING`. Without the unary minus it's a syntax error.

Comment: @Jens, no, did you try? It is not a syntax error. As I explain, `(uintmax_t)` is evaluated to `(0)` by the preprocessor in `#if` and similar. Then the thing is `(0)-1UL` which is an unsigned expression. The preprocessor *must* evaluate all integer expressions as `intmax_t` or `uintmax_t`. So that expression is the maximum unsigned expression that the preprocess may have.

Comment: @us2012, I hadn't seen that remark of OP. In a part of the implementation of a standard library routine there *may* be some issues, in particular if they want their code run even with non-compliant compilers. Still such a thing should never stand as such, without an explanation and without a surrounding `#ifndef ULONG_MAX`.

Comment: @JensGustedt That remark is a comment on the answer below. The relevant code also has a surrounding `#ifndef` in glibc. I get the feeling that the OP was trying to trick people into saying "yeah this guy who wrote that part of glibc is an idiot" when there might have been good reasons to do so. Considering the strong wording of your post ('crap', 'very bad') maybe you could add a note that what you're saying is certainly true for normal application code on a compliant compiler, but not necessarily for such special purposes?

Comment: @us2012, and in fact looking at the source it *is* protected by an `#ifndef`. So this probably only rarely triggered until now :). From the following lines you also see that *then* they also suppose that `long` has just the most significant bit of `unsigned long` as sign bit. Reasonable assumptions if the compiler didn't provide any of these macros by itself.

Comment: @us2012, I put some more conditionals in. Still I don't think that this is good code, even in the implementation of a standard function. You may observe that the other `#ifndef` hacks around that point provide comments about the reason for doing so. This one doesn't, so any reasoning why this might be in there is pure speculation.

Comment: @JensGustedt Yes I tried with GCC. The preprocessor has no idea what a cast is. It works in terms of tokens only. `#if ((int)1) == 1` is a syntax error that must be diagnosed. For the preprocessor, `(uintmax_t)` is a parenthesized expression, not a cast.

Comment: Did you read what I wrote? You missed the point: the tiny little `-` sign in `(uintptr_t)-1`. This makes it a valid expression for the preprocessor because the `-` becomes a binary minus, then.

Comment: Well, that maybe so, but you mislead the reader with "Recasting of expression may make sense if they are used in the preprocessor." It's not a cast. It shouldn't look like one. It's *bad advice* because it'll break for nonnegative values. It's bad advice because it sort of works for arcane and obfuscated reasons only for negative values. It's bad advice because the casual reader might get the wrong idea about the preprocessor understanding casts. That's enough of reasons to entirely condemn the construct, IMNSHO :-)

Comment: @Jens, ah, now your criticism is becoming constructive. I will look how to improve my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Jens, you shouldn't condemn the construct entirely. In rare circumstances you want macros to expand to a certain value *and* type, and you want to have that value in `#if`s also. This is the only way to achieve that, AFAIK. But I admit that it has some taste of black magic if it is not explained properly.

Comment: @JensGustedt Fair enough. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Why the "Even `~0UL` should not be used for that value, since unsigned long may (theoretically) have padding bits."?  Even with padding bits or not, the result is the same: an `unsigned long` with maximum value.

Comment: "-1 will always be the maximum value of an unsigned type." is factually off.  The maximum value of an unsigned type in never a negative value.  Assigning a `-1` to an unsigned results in a maximal value, but that value is not -1.  Suggest re-write.

Answer (score 0):

They are trying to ensure that the type of the value `0` is `unsigned long`.  When you assign zero to a variable, it gets cast to the appropriate type.

In this case, if `0` doesn't happen to be an `unsigned long` then the `~` operator will be applied to whatever other type it happens to be and the result of that will be cast.

This would be a problem if the compiler decided that `0` is a `short` or `char`.

However, the type *after* the `~` operator should remain the same.  So they are being overly cautious with the outer cast, but perhaps the inner cast is justified.

They could of course have specified the correct zero type to begin with by writing `~0UL`.